# Please explain in simple terms what the bitwise negation (~) operator does in bash

Tags: bash

I am studying bitwise operations in bash and understand all the other operations, but this one. It will be a great help if someone can explain (with examples) what the negation (~) operator does in bitwise operations. Couldn't understand from what I read here and elsewhere. TIA!

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75196/237982

Comment: Turns out needed to think two's complement to understand it. thanks. seems obvious now

Comment: actually, bitwise negation has nothing to do with two's complement ... it is the interpretation of the result that could be influenced by two's complement

Comment: @jsotola could you please elaborate?